# How to create session in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, jakarta-ee

I want to create session in Spring. but i don't want to use
 **HttpSession session**

is there any other  easy way in Spring.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring doesn't create any session. It it the application server who does it. This looks like XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1.We cannot create a session,container will takes care of creating a session for an given request.

2.Container will  passes the session object to controller.

3.We can use that object by putting our requried values or object in session